# When two applications having same app link url then which one is open by default. I have to give priority to my application

Tags: android, android-app-links

When two applications having same app link url having same intent then which one is open by default. I have to give priority to my application. How to give priority to our application.

When two applications having same app link url then which one is open by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.